# Find $\mathbb{E}(X^2 - X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ with binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

$n \in \mathbb{N}, p \in (0, 1), X \sim \text{Bin}(n, p)$.

1. Find $\mathbb{E}(X^2 - X)$. Hint: for which $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$ is $k^2 - k = 0$?
2. Use the above to find $\text{Var}(X)$.

My answer:

1. It is linear so:
   $$
   \mathbb{E}(X^2 - X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)
   $$
   We can find $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ with the formula for $Var(x)$:
   \begin{align*}
   \operatorname{Var}(X) & = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 \\
   \mathbb{E}(X^2) &= \operatorname{Var}(X) + \mathbb{E}(X)^2 \\
   &= np(1-p) + (np)^2 \\
   &= np - np^2 + n^2p^2
   \end{align*}

Now we can calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^2 - X)$ in $n$ and $p$:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X^2 - X) &= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X) \\
&= (np - np^2 + n^2p^2) - np \\
&= -np^2 + n^2p^2 \\
&= (np)^2 - np^2
\end{align*}

2. I don't understand the question? I have already calculated $\text{Var}(X)$ right?

Comment: @JoshBone OP does include a square...

Comment: @Golden_Ratio oops, I misread. OP uses the formula for variance, but does not derive it.

Comment: so i answered both questions in one?

Comment: Since your ultimate goal is to find $Var(X),$ I don't think knowledge of $Var(X)$ is allowed in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the hint intended for you to write $X$ as a sum of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables $B_i$:

$$X^2-X=\left(\sum_i B_i \right)^2-\sum_i B_i=\sum_i B_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j} B_iB_j -\sum_i B_i=\sum_{i\neq j} B_iB_j,$$

where the final equality uses the hint ($B_i^2-B_i=0$ since $B_i$ takes values $1,0$).

Hence,

$$E[X^2-X]=\sum_{i\neq j} E[B_i]E[B_j]=\sum_{i\neq j} p^2=(n^2-n)p^2.$$

From here, compute the variance using the approach you did for part 1.

Comment: How do you go from $\sum_{i\neq j} E[B_i]E[B_j]$ to$ \sum_{i\neq j} p^2$?

Comment: @Willem the mean of each Bernoulli random variable is $p$

Comment: @Willem But you can use 1 to back out $E[X^2]$, which you would then use in the variance computation

Comment: Ok thanks and now 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2 - X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)
$$ so 
$$
(n^2-n)p^2 = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)
$$ and $ \mathbb{E}(X) = np$ so
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = (n^2-n)p^2 + np$$ and then calculate $Var(x)$ with this?

Comment: @Willem exactly

Comment: Thanks I calculated it and found exactly $np(1 - p)$, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144619/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-willem).